# Snapshot test using vue is failing with "TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

The component itself works on the page with no errors.

So does storybook, the only issue is the unit test.

```
import { mount } from '../../vue';
import { createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import SessionGymChart from '@/components/SessionGymChart.vue';

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(Vuex);

const defaultprops = {
  endDateOveride: '',
  totalHours: 0,
  sessionsTotal: 1,
  isLoading: false,
  hasTooMuchData: false,
  swapChart: false,
  chartData: {}
};

describe('SessionGymChart', () => {
  let store;
  beforeEach(() => {
    store = new Vuex.Store({
      state: {
        user: { billing: true },
        chartData: {
          days: 10,
          sessions: [
            {
              id: '324365egdfgfd',
              sessionReference: '056343',
              dateStarted: '2022-08-26T16:23:14.909Z',
              dateEnded: '2022-08-26T16:23:22.000Z',
              userId: 'dfgdfgdfg545645',
              userDisplayName: 'Tester'
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      mutations: {},
      actions: {}
    });
  });
```

Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong?
There is a computed property where it breaks on the component. It seems like it can't access the sessions data (saying undefined) and I'm not sure why as it is inside defaultprops.

This is where it shows to be breaking in the component, at a computed property and this shows on the snapshot error.

```
gymSeries() {
      const { sessions } = this.chartData ? this.chartData : {};
    > if (sessions.length === 0) return {};
                                           ^
      else {
         const sessionsUsage = sessions.map(x => {
         return {
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually returns `undefined` if `this.chartData` is `undefined`:

```
const { sessions } = this.chartData ? this.chartData : {};
```

The problem there is that you're destructuring `chartData`, and you expect the return value of the ternary statement to be an object that *contains* a `sessions` property.
If `chartData` is `undefined`, that results in:

```
const { sessions } = {};
```

You can fix that by adding an empty `sessions` property:

```
const { sessions } = this.chartData ? this.chartData : { sessions: {} };
```

Or, shorter, using optional chaining:

```
const sessions = this.chartData?.sessions || {};
```